# Odoo How to make custom report, AttributeError

Tags: python, xml, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-8

I'm trying to make a custom report. I used this documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html and looked at the add-on "sale" to have an exemple of report. I wanted to do a first test so I used the minimal viable template of the documentation.

Here is my template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
            <template id="report_demand_document">
                    <t t-call="report.html_container">
                            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                                    <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                                            <div class="page">
                                                    <h2>Propositions</h2>
                                                    <p>Vote du <span t-field="o.date"/></p>
                                            </div>  
                                    </t>
                            </t>
                    </t>
            </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Here is the report call

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
            <report
                    id="report_demand"
                    string="Propositions en cours"
                    model="report"
                    report_type="qweb-pdf"
                    name="report.report_demand"
                    file="report.report_demand"
                    attachment="'Propositions' + str(object.date) +'.pdf'"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

And I get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'report' object has no attribute '_check_wkhtmltopdf'
```

The full log if needed :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 540, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 577, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 313, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 310, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 806, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 406, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 143, in check_wkhtmltopdf
    return request.registry['report']._check_wkhtmltopdf()
AttributeError: 'report' object has no attribute '_check_wkhtmltopdf'
```

I searched for "_check_wkhtmltopdf" on google but found nothing about it in Odoo neither did I find any occurence of my error on it.
What does that error mean? Do I have to install something? (I'm using Odoo-8)

Comment: what script did you run? May you mention it or copy the code?

Comment: I didn't redefined the script, I go on my form, use "print" and select the one I created.

Comment: Sorry I forgot "Odoo" in the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i see it correct, then you've overriden the Odoo model/class `report`, which handles all the stuff for rendering documents, etc.

```xml
<report
    id="report_demand"
    string="Propositions en cours"
    model="report"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="report.report_demand"
    file="report.report_demand"
    attachment="'Propositions' + str(object.date) +'.pdf'"/>
```

Here you define the report on model `report`. Other examples will show you values like `sale.order` or `account.invoice` on its report definitions.

Please don't declare a new ORM model `report`. Just use another name like `test.report` or something like that.

Let's talk about undoing this mistake: change the attribute `_name` on your test model and restart the server. And of course change your report definition to the new model name. Now update your module. That should do the trick.